# How do I chain the same methods to multiple observables?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

Suppose I have the following service with the following methods that make some API calls:

```
class MyService {
    constructor(protected http: HttpClient) { } 

    getItems() {
        return this.http
            .get(`/api/items`)
            .catch(this.handleError)
            .finally(() => { return; });
    }

    getItem(id: string) {
        return this.http
            .get(`/api/items/${id}`)
            .catch(this.handleError)
            .finally(() => { return; });
    }

    addItem(item: Object) {
        return this.http
            .post(`/api/items`, JSON.stringify(item))
            .catch(this.handleError)
            .finally(() => { return; });
    }

    editItem(id: string, item: Object) {
        return this.http
            .put(`/api/items/${id}`, JSON.stringify(item))
            .catch(this.handleError)
            .finally(() => { return; });
    }

    private handleError(err: any) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}
```

Notice how I have the identical `.catch(...)` and `.finally(...)` lines of code repeated in multiple places. I want to chain those methods in one spot to reduce code repetition.

This is what I've done so far, but it breaks the readability of the chaining. It seems to me like there's probably another way to do this and still maintain the order of the chaining. I'm still a novice when it comes to observables.

```
class MyService {
    constructor(protected http: HttpClient) { } 

    getItems() {
        return this.applyExtras(this.http.get(`/api/items`));
    }

    getItem(id: string) {
        return this.applyExtras(this.http.get(`/api/items/${id}`));
    }

    addItem(item: Object) {
        return this.applyExtras(this.http.post(`/api/items`, JSON.stringify(item)));
    }

    editItem(id: string, item: Object) {
        return this.applyExtras(this.http.put(`/api/items/${id}`, JSON.stringify(item)));
    }

    private applyExtras(obs: Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
        return obs
            .catch(this.handleError)
            .finally(() => { return; });
    }

    private handleError(err: any) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: Another option is to just handle the error/finalization on the subscription if this is used in only one location.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I didn't state it but that's exactly what I was trying to refactor. We have a couple dozen services with methods that all have nearly identical `catch` and `finally` operators on them, and I was trying to move that into a base class where I only need to add them in one spot. But you're right, that would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using at least RxJS 5.5.0 then you can use `pipeable` operators to share pipelines of common operators.

```
class MyService {
    constructor(protected http: HttpClient) { } 

    private withErrorHandler: any = [
      catchError(this.handleError),
      finalize(() => {})
    ]

    getItems() {
        return this.http
            .get(`/api/items`)
            .pipe(...withErrorHandler)
    }
}
```

Alternatively if you don't want to use the pipeable syntax or you have an earlier version of RxJS then you can use `let` instead.

```
private withErrorHandler: any = (source) => 
  source.catch(this.handleError).finally(() => {})

getItems() {
  return this.http
     .get(`/api/items`)
     .let(withErrorHandler)
}
```

Comment: Since I originally asked this question, we have upgraded our project which requires a newer version of RxJS, and all of our existing observable chains were converted to pipes. Yes, it's a piece of cake to do this kind of thing now. Also, it looks like `let` was exactly what I was looking for. Never would've gathered that from the name.